# Code Coverage for json.deserialize

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I have the apex class called from a trigger:

```
@future
public static void TaskList(String strJSON)
{
    List<Task > TaskList = (List<Task>) json.deserialize(strJSON, List<Task >.class);
    update TaskList;
}
```

I can't seem to cover it with a test class. Any help guys? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to do? Idea is very simple -- you create some tasks in test method, add them to list, insert, change some value in code, perform deserialization and then call your method. Then check that tasks got updated in database

Comment: code coverage for the trigger is fine its just the part where this part is being called upon stays red.

Answer (score 5):

To get asynchronous code executed in a test, you need to add:

```
Test.startTest();

// Code to get your trigger to run

Test.stopTest();

// Assert results
```

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm?search_text=test.stopTest) explains that:

> All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected
>   by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes
>   are run synchronously.

Without these calls asynchronous code such as `@future` won't run at all in tests.